# a.b.c.d type property access when undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, null-check

```js
    // option 1
    let val = a.b.c.d || null; 
    // this gives error if a.b.c is undefined or a.b is undefined etc.

    // option 2: alternate version
    let val2 = null;
    if (a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c.d) {
        val2 = a.b.c.d;
    }
```

Is there an elegant way of writing the above code that is somewhat similar to option 1?

Comment: You can use `try{...} catch(ex){ default assumptions}`

Comment: Unfortunately there's no efficient and elegant way for that in Javascript right now, other than avoiding being in this situation. You often end up with some helpers ([example](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/libs/Miaou.js#L27)).

Comment: my life gets easier if a.b.c.d returned undefined if a.b.c was undefined; but no!

Comment: Please search thoroughly before posting. More on searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: Thanks TJ, I will learn more about search and its importance to the "world wide web". Was curious, is searching a problem or reading long verbose questions and answers an issue?